# bad cmake executable vscode

Tags: compiling, snap, c++, cmake, visual-studio-code

I've recently freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04, and VSCode, meant for c++. I added the C/C++, CMake and CMake Tools extensions. Then I cloned one of my old github repos for testing and tried to Cmake:configure from the command pallete, but I got this error.

```
Bad CMake executable "/snap/bin/cmake". Is it installed or settings contain the correct path (cmake.cmakePath)?
```

I've looked through the CMake tools extension github repo for answers, and it appears to be [some kind of an issue regarding snaps](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/838)? I'm not that sure what exactly they're talking about, but I got that its a bug in CMake Tools, however I didnt find a solution for this. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove Snap'ed cmake by

```
snap remove cmake
```

and install deb-packaged version by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake

sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install cmake-extras
```

and then restart VSCode.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The cmake version that comes with Snap is more recent on my `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`:

```
$ apt show cmake
Package: cmake
Version: 3.16.3-1ubuntu1
```

while the Snap version I installed

```
cmake version 3.22.2
```

So I preferred to use `/snap/cmake/current/bin/cmake` as `CMake Path` (as recommended [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/838#issuecomment-548712154):
"It works when you use /snap/cmake/current/bin/cmake as CMake Path. All snap executables seem to be just symbolic links to /usr/bin/snap, and that seems to work fine when called from a terminal but apparently not from the CMake extension in VSCode ...").